# bonjour + bluetooth + iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bonjour

I have a bonjour service written in C# that works over a standard wireless network with iOS (iPhone/iPad). I am trying to configure the service so that it works with a bluetooth connection.  I'm new to bluetooth so I might be doing something wrong. I've paired my iPad to my laptop (it comes up as a Bluetooth Peripheral Device in device manager but without a driver.)

The iPad won't connect to the bluetooth service and I'm not sure what else I need to do. What am I missing?

[update]

After looking a bit more i see that the iPhone and the iPad support PAN bluetooth. But it's still not working. I can not create a PAN network with my iPhone. Is this a limitation imposed by apple?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled Bluetooth tethering on your iPhone/ipad ? 
I think this needs to be enabled (via your service provider - ATT in US) for connecting via PAN profile

Comment: No, I have not. Do you think that would enable my application to find a bonjour service?

Comment: i suggest you try enabling tethering only then you will be able to connect via PAN to iOS device

Comment: I've confirmed that the PAN is available if enable internet tethering. This won't work for my applications mainly due to the giant blue bar it places at the top of the phone. I'm currently applying for the MFi program to see if they have a solution for these kinds of issues for emulation that does not involve tethering.